# Strange bug with the Subdivision Surface Modifier

Tags: modeling

I just started using Blender yesterday. I'm trying to create a shotgun model but I've encountered a strange bug (I think) with the Subdivision Surface modifier.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Why is this happening? I've tried deleting faces and edges and putting them back but nothing seems to get rid of these pinches.

Comment: Could you upload blend file to: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/?

Answer (score 2):

Check for faces *inside* the mesh. These are referred to as *interior faces* and they mess things up in ways similar to what's going on in your model.

One way to find them is:

1. Go to *Edit Mode* (<kbd>Tab</kbd>)
2. Make sure to deselect everything (<kbd>A</kbd> key)
3. Open the *Select* menu (bottom of the *3D Viewport* window)
4. Choose *Select All by Trait > Interior Faces*

If anything ends up selected, hit <kbd>X</kbd> or *Delete*.

If that doesn't work, you'll have to hunt it down by hand. To do that:

1. Enter *Edit Mode*
2. Turn off your *Subdiv* modifier (eye icon in the modifier pane),
3. Delete a face near the problem area,
4. Rotate your view around and peek inside.

If you see an interior face, select and delete. And when you're done, of course, replace the face you deleted.

Comment: In addition to what was said also look for duplicate geometry which is far more common, then in *Edit Mode* select everything, press `W` > Remove Doubles.

Comment: ... and, that often, that the quickest way to find flaws in the  topology is to attempt Alt-selecting edge loops. If the selection fails in an unexpected place, that's where to look.

Answer (score 0):

If @Sackadoo 's answer didn't work for you, you may want to fix the flipped mesh normals, in 2.7 it's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> , in 2.8 it's <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> . (You have to select the mesh with problems first in edit mode)